# Code to list all permissions for SharePoint Folders

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm after some C# code to recursively enumerate all the folders in a SharePoint web site and list the permissions applying to them to be run from a Sharepoint client machine. Can anyone provide or point me to an example?

The following code can perform this function on a server using SPSite object   ( from  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c7c5735-039e-4cb9-a2b5-58d70a10793f/get-permissions-group-from-folders-tree-view-on-a-doc-library?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) but I need to run it using SharePoint Client code

```
public static void getPermissionsOfFolders()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
                {
                    SPList list = web.GetList("/Lists/List2");
                    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Folders)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ID: "+item["ID"]+"--"+item.SortType);
                        if (SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder == item.SortType)
                        {
                            SPRoleAssignmentCollection roles = item.RoleAssignments;
                            foreach (SPRoleAssignment role in roles)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("~");
                                Console.WriteLine("Name: "+role.Member.Name);

                                SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection bindings = role.RoleDefinitionBindings;

                                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                                doc.LoadXml(bindings.Xml);
                                XmlNodeList itemList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Role");
                                foreach (XmlNode currNode in itemList)
                                {
                                    string s = currNode.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString();
                                    Console.WriteLine("Permission Level: "+s);
                                }
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
                        }  
                    }                                  
                }
            }
        }
```

Code below fails with exception "Property ListItemAllFields not found"  as shown below on `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()`

```
   private void ListSPPermissions3()
    {
            string sSite = "http://server2012a/sites/TestDocs/";
            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(sSite))
            {
                Site site = clientContext.Site;
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");

                clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders); //load the client object list.RootFolder.Folders
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                int FolderCount = list.RootFolder.Folders.Count;

                foreach  (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder folder in list.RootFolder.Folders)
                {

                        RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssCol = folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments;

                        clientContext.Load(roleAssCol); 
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // Exception property ListItemAllFields not found

                        foreach (RoleAssignment roleAss in roleAssCol)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(roleAss.Member.Title);
                        }
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least the following flaws with your example:

1. The specified example only allows to retrieve folders one level
   beneath:

   ```
   clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders); //load the client object       list.RootFolder.Folders
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   ```
2. Role assignments could be retrieved using a single request to the
   server (see the below example), hence there is no need to perform
   multiple requests to retrieve role assignments per folder.
3. `Folder.ListItemAllFields` property is supported only in SharePoint
   **2013** CSOM API

---

Having said that i would recommend to consider the following example to enumerate folder permissions:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{

     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
     var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery());
     ctx.Load(items, icol => icol.Include(i => i.RoleAssignments.Include( ra => ra.Member), i => i.DisplayName ));
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     foreach (var item in items)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} folder permissions",item.DisplayName);
        foreach (var assignment in item.RoleAssignments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(assignment.Member.Title);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: This code lists all the folder names and permissions but does not indicate the folder URLs. By adding item.Id to the retrieved item properties  as below:
 `ctx.Load(items, icol => icol.Include(i => i.RoleAssignments.Include(ra => ra.Member), i => i.DisplayName,i=>i.Id));`
 I can get DocLibRowID in table AllDocs, from whence I can get DirName (and thus the URL), but is there an easier way ?

Comment: Is there a way of expanding the SharePoint groups to show which AD users are in them e.g.
   Test Docs Owners
   Test Docs Visitors
   Test Docs Members

Comment: Is there any documentation that shows the relationship between webUri and listTitle in the above code ? I'd like to understand the path structure as I can't access a list in Shared Documents on the SP server I'm working on. I just keep getting the list is not part of url error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because the SharePoint SDK you are using is pre-SharePoint 2013 CSOM.

`Folder.ListItemAllFields` 
 property is available in SharePoint 2013 CSOM

For SharePoint 2010, you have to access folders like list items

```
ListItem item = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents").GetItemById(<item ID>);
```

and then get the RoleAssignments for the items.

Comment: This code works well but only gives the folder name, not the Url. How can I get the URL of each folder?